# Add combo box items from data layer c#

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I have a data layer class where I create all the SQL statements inside methods. In my UI layer i have a combo box. **What I want to do is, I want to fill the combo box from the data layer, not from the UI layer**. 
So far I have typed this code inside data layer....

```
public void ComboImageList()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ImageName FROM [ImageWithTags]", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
          string name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ImageName"));
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } 
}
```

Since I cannot access UI layer directly from Data layer, I dont know how to pass the values. I dont know if I can pass the combo box to the data layer or I have to pass the string to the UI layer.

can someone help?

Comment: Never try to access GUI elements from the data layer, this is a bad design because it violates separation of concerns. Maybe you should read a tutorial first.

Comment: @FlatEric sorry forgot to tell you that I have a Business Layer too. I know I cannot access UI layer from Data Layer. Thats Why I have posted this...

Comment: Do it the other way round. I don't know which exact approach you are using but you should trigger the function of the data layer from the higher layer (in MVVM for example from the ViewModel). You can also use DependencyInjection to have better decoupling between the layers but this would be too long to explain here.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do that, because such design leads to numerous problems: awkward testing, hard to refactor, relying on particular database and UI controls where you shouldn't, it will be hard to reuse DAL from other places.

Diagram

```
User -> UI -> DAL -> Database
                         |
User <- UI <-  DAL <------
```

Proper way of doing this will be to have a method in DAL like

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
{
    // execute your SQL and return result as some abstract collection
    using( /* connection setup */
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ImageName FROM [ImageWithTags]", con))
        {
            con.Open();  // check this, maybe it could be opened in first using
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                yield return  reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ImageName"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in UI layer you just call it like so

```
public void FillCombos()
{
    var repo = new DALRepo();
    var names = repo.GetNames();

    // now you can assign names to your combobox
    // ...
}
```